# Getting all the title tags from a div using bs4 error

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the title tags from all the items in a page using bs4 and then print out all the titles. If I do *print(soup.find("a", attrs={"class": "detLink"})["title"])* I get the title for only one of them.  If I switch "select" to findAll or find_all I get an error msg saying:

```
 print(soup.findAll("a", attrs={"class": "detLink"})["title"])
 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

This is the my code:

```
def test():
    url_to_scrape = "https://test.com"
    r = requests.get(url_to_scrape)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")
    print(soup.select("a", attrs={"class": "detLink"})["title"])

test()
```

How can I get the title of all the items?

Comment: Hi Paul, I saw you last question (now deleted) about a phishy script. If you wish to talk about it... I may have an idea for you. Join me on [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/bessetteweb/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
def test():
    url_to_scrape = "https://test.com"
    r = requests.get(url_to_scrape)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")
    titles = [div["title"] 
              for div in soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class": "detLink"})]
    print(titles)

test()
```

Effectively using a list comprehension for the titles.